# ImageMagic library with Cmake: linking error

Tags: c, linker, cmake, imagemagick

I'm programming in C. I want use ImageMagick library but some fuction can't be resolved.

This is my cMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(WebServer)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")

set(SOURCE_FILES io.c server.c lock_fcntl.c sig_handler.c thread_job.c    msg_parser.c)
set(LIB http-parser-master/http_parser.c )

set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT true)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT ON)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS ImageWand)

include_directories(header)
include_directories(http-parser-master)

#include_directories(/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(server ${SOURCE_FILES} ${LIB})
add_executable(client client.c io.c)
add_executable(main main.c io.c)

target_link_libraries(main ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(server Threads::Threads)
```

and this is the source main.c:

```
#include <ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
#include "basic.h"

void convert_image(char *path, float quality_factor, char *out) {

    int width, height;
    MagickWand *n_wand = NULL;

    MagickWandGenesis();

    m_wand = (struct MagickWand *) NewMagickWand();


    MagickReadImage(m_wand,"logo:");

    width = MagickGetImageWidth(m_wand);
    height = MagickGetImageHeight(m_wand);

    if((width /= 2) < 1)width = 1;
    if((height /= 2) < 1)height = 1;

    MagickResizeImage(m_wand,width,height,LanczosFilter,1);

    MagickSetImageCompressionQuality(m_wand,95);

    MagickWriteImage(m_wand,"logo_resize.jpg");

   if(m_wand)m_wand = (struct MagickWand *) DestroyMagickWand(m_wand);

    MagickWandTerminus();
}
```

On build I get this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o
[ 66%] Linking C executable main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o: nella funzione "convert_image":
/home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:14: riferimento non    definito a "MagickWandGenesis"
/home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:16: riferimento non      definito a "NewMagickWand"
/home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:19: riferimento non definito a "MagickReadImage"
/home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:22: riferimento non definito a "MagickSetImageCompressionQuality"
/home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:25: riferimento non definito a "MagickWriteImage"
 /home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:28: riferimento non definito a "DestroyMagickWand"
 /home/emanuele/ClionProjects/WebServer/main.c:30: riferimento non  definito a "MagickWandTerminus"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [main] Errore 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Errore 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/rule] Errore 2
make: *** [main] Errore 2
```

ImageMagick is correctly installed and it work by command line. How to solve?

Comment: you should check in cmake if your library has been found or not. Have you checked the value of `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES` ? Maybe you also need to set the library path too.

Comment: if I add `find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS MagickWand REQUIRED)` I obtain `Error:Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARY) (found version "7.0.3-0")`, but i don't know how to fix

Comment: That is why you get the linker errors. Because your `${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}` is empty after that. if your library is not in the default lib path's you can add additional custom paths to find_package to add the folder where the library is located.

Comment: However the library is in the default lib path. it is in /usr/local/lib and the headers in /usr/local/include

Comment: does the library have a file like `<name>Config.cmake` or `<lower-case-name>-config.cmake`

Comment: i don't find it

Comment: find_package won't work then. Instead of the variable `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES` just use the name of the library (without the lib prefix and without the extension)

Comment: it work! But i don't understand why find_package don't work. Everywhere i read to use it, also in cmake documentation

Comment: find_package looks for a .cmake file which sets the variables (see the documentation of find_package) not every library provides this that's why it does not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you get the linker errors because `find_package` cannot find a configuration for the library.

`find_package` looks for a file in the format of `<name>Config.cmake` or `<lower-case-name>-config.cmake` which will set the necessary variables.

Not every library has these files and when not you have to manually specify the library name in target_link_library(...) and other configurations (like library path and include path etc. if necessary)